# ERROR Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm deploying my website on the server.

My website is done using asp.net c# 4 and EF 4.

I receive this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Any idea how could I fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run it on a version of ASP.NET which is running CLR v2. It's hard to know *exactly* what's going on without more information about how you've deployed it, what version of IIS you're running etc (and to be frank I wouldn't be very much help at that point anyway, though others would). But basically, check your IIS and ASP.NET set-up, and make sure that everything is running v4. Check your application pool configuration, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your answer, hosting company is running for the server IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008. could be a problem of the hosting provider that has a pool set to not v4?

Comment: @GibboK: Does the hosting company *claim* to support ASP.NET v4? They may not even have .NET 4 installed... it sounds like you need to be talking to them directly.

Comment: Thanks Jon, we are working on the problem with the hosting company... it seems that .net 4 was uninstalled four our pool. Thanks for your time on this question.

Answer (score 5):

Just Add  AjaxControlToolkit.dll to your Reference folder.

On your Project Solution, Right Click on Reference Folder > Add Reference > browse AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

Then build.

Comment: yes reference is included and AjaxControlToolkit.dll is included in the BIN folder... any ideas?

Comment: Can you create new solution that is lower than 4 (3.5 or below) and have a test if it will work on it.

Answer (score 5):

check below link in which you can download suitable AjaxControlToolkit which suits your .NET version.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475

AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4.zip - used for .NET 4.0

AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET35.zip - used for .NET 3.5

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Might sound obvious but do you definitely have AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your bin?

Comment: I think it's there, otherwise there wouldn't be an error message of: "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"

Comment: I completely missed the second sentence of that error. Didn't see the scrollbars. It that case it does sound like an older version of NET :)

Comment: DaveHogan do you mean hosting provider is running an older version of asp.net?

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with Source safe then make a new directory and take the latest there, this solved my issue...thanks

Answer (score -1):

Right click in Project / **Clean**

That always works for me