# Instaling dlls on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to install ajaxtoolkit.dll and some other dlls on to a production Win 2008 servers. Dragging it won't work, I can't install SDK, and I don't speak PowerShell.

I guess the big picture is this: This is new SharePoint 2010 server and I porting over a heavily branded portal app with several custom webparts.

In Moss 2007 days, I would just drag my dlls, and run *.wps files to install webparts.

Thanks for your input.

Risho

Edited: I've installed 64 bit SDK on a deve server and then copied the gacutil and its config file in the c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder. Ran the command /i AjaxControlToolkit.dll and got this error:

Failure adding assembly to the cache: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Seems like this is a common issue.

Isn't there a way to create an install project that you would run form a msi, or exe file that would drop all my dlls and webparts automagically? I mean how to the pros do it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two questions.

The second is the more specific question regarding AjaxControlToolkit.dll. For that, take a look at [ERROR Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695657/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-ajaxcontroltoolkit-or-one-of-its-depende).

As to your original question, as long as you only need to deploy the DLL (in other words, you don't need to run an install program, modify the web.config, etc), the way to go is to place your DLL into your WSP solution package. This is easier than ever with Visual Studio 2010. For more information, see [How to: Add and Remove Additional Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231595.aspx) and [Including additional assemblies in the WSP with Visual Studio SharePoint development tools](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/).

Comment: I'm failing to see any relevance in the first link you're suggesting. As far as to my original question, I'm modifying the default.master by adding <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %> and <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/> and I need to drop the tolkit in the GAC.